# LIBGDX/Android - How can scale a view?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to get a bar at the bottom of the screen where ads can be placed and have found no way of doing so. What I am trying to do is pretty much this (below)
[image: Gap between bottom of screen and view]

You can see that there is a gap for adverts to fit in at the bottom, meaning that the view of the game doesn't actually take up the entire screen.

How can I achieve this? I am looking for maybe a way to scale the view to change its height but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You put both in a relative layout.  Make the bar aligned to the parent bottom, then make the game view align to the top of the bar.